# 'Component.GetComponent<T>()' is a method, which is not valid in the given context

Tags: unity-game-engine, components, sprite, move, dotween

'Component.GetComponent()' is a method, which is not valid in the given context
this error in my code;

GetComponent().DOMove(finalPos,2f);

Comment: You didn’t provide a component type

Comment: You need to specify what component should be gotten. Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) to see the different ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Change
`GetComponent().DOMove(finalPos,2f);`
to
`GetComponent<ComponentYouWantToGet>().DOMove(finalPos,2f);`